# Find List of String which mache in Text using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am getting stuck in this situation.

```
 public void findListOfPattern(){
      String text = "abce1213abcd231asdf";
      String find = "1213|231|1232"; 
      Pattern part = Pattern.compile(find);
      Matcher mat = part.matcher(text);
      System.out.println(mat.find()); //True
}
```

Able to get true result if any of string in **find** get match.
I want list of matcher from **text**.
There text can large with more find string and also find string can more.
In find : 1213,231,1232 are separates.

**Result should be like :- 1213,231**

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `mat.group()` to return the desired match.

Typically you'd loop until `mat.find()` returns `true` and print all matches successively by invoking `mat.group()`.

You can then build your expected result `String` by concatenating the outcome of `mat.group()` as you wish, e.g. with a `StringBuilder`.

**Notes**

- API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29).
- You **need** to invoke `Matcher#find` in order for `Matcher#group` to yield any result and not throw `IllegalStateException`
- Your `Pattern` only has the default group. If you'd used parenthesis or named groups (from Java 7), you could also invoke overloads [Matcher#group(int group)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) or [Matcher#group(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks let me try.

Comment: I am unable to get list of string which one is in text.